# An error occured when using scipy.misc.imread

Tags: python, machine-learning, deep-learning

I am developing a CNN to classify images, and my images are stored in a folder which contains some subfolders, and now I want to use scipy.misc.imread to read images then to feed to tensorflow

My codes is as follows:

```
import numpy as np
import os
import tensorflow as tf
import pandas as pd
from scipy import misc
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder



IMAGE_SIZE = 150
data = pd.read_excel('class.xlsx')
root = 'dragonfly'




def label_image(image):
    le = LabelEncoder().fit(data.种) 
    classes = list(le.classes_)
    for i, item in enumerate (classes):
        if os.path.dirname(image) == item:
            label = i
    return label


def create_train_data():
    train_data = []
    for files in os.walk(root):
        for file in files:
            image = misc.imread(file)
            label = label_image(file)
            image = misc.imresize(image, (IMAGE_SIZE, IMAGE_SIZE))
            train_data.append(np.array(image),np.array(label))
    return train_data


train_data = create_train_data()
```

The 'dragonfly' is the folder which contains all images I have. And now an error occured:

PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'dragonfly'

Comment: Looks like you don't have permission to access the folders...

Comment: But actually when I don't use misc.imread, I can load the folder into my model, but I don't know how to solve it

Comment: Before running this, can you check this: list_of_files =  os.listdir(root). And see whether all images names come in the list or not.

Comment: I am getting this problem too. I am running the kernel as an adminstrator and the file directory populates properly using os.listdir(path). I don't understand how the director can't be accessed.